# wp-admin blocking causing http error on uploads

Tags: wp-admin

I'm using this function to prevent users apart from admin from getting to the backend of wordpress. (Note, that addition to allow ajax requests too):

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_users' );

function my_block_users() {
      $isAjax = (defined('DOING_AJAX') && true === DOING_AJAX) ? true : false;

    if(!$isAjax) {

        if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit;
        }

    }
}
```

Trouble is, it causes an http error when uploading images etc. Does anyone know a work around for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on my side. Try disabling your plugins and test again.

Btw. You could use `admin_init` instead of the `init` action hook. This way, the snippet will only be executed on admin requests. This way, you can remove the `is_admin()` check in the function.

Comment: It totally does work. It was red herring, not quite sure what was temporarily causing the http error. Anyway, working now, so yey! Also, good point about admin_init. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.